# Handling callbacks in code that is like an inheritance tree

Tags: javascript, inheritance, callback

I am working on a javascript based character sheet system for role playing games. Within the specific type of RPG I am trying to implement there exists something of an inheritance tree, so that there are the basic RPG-system rules, there are more specific rules for a given setting within that RPG-system, and then there might be differences between specific versions of that setting.

For a given user interaction the code should execute some actions for the overall RPG-system, and some other code for the specific setting and version that is being used.

Currently I am handling this by doing something in the form of:

```
CharacterSheet.prototype.handleSomeUserInteraction()  {
    this.handleSomeUserInteractionForSystem();
    this.handleSomeUserInteractionForSetting();
    this.handleSomeUserInteractionForVersion();
}

// Empty implementations here to avoid errors, this will be overwritten with a
// function that does the actual handling in a separate file
CharacterSheet.prototype.handleSomeUserInteractionForSystem()  {}
CharacterSheet.prototype.handleSomeUserInteractionForSetting()  {}
CharacterSheet.prototype.handleSomeUserInteractionForVersion()  {}
```

The above is of course inelegant and not efficient - some interactions don't require handling at all three levels, but I still have to call an empty callback. (It should be noted that, of course, I don't know in advance which of these callbacks are needed - it depends on the particular system/setting/version.)

Ideally I would like to achieve the following:

- It should be lightweight - in rare circumstances these callbacks need to be called maybe hundred times per second.
- Only required/non-empty callbacks should be called.
- The interface to registering a callback should be intuitive and clean, so that other developers who are otherwise unfamiliar with the rest of the code can use it easily develop their own RPG system/setting/version code.

  - I.e. it should be obvious which parts of the code can be extended (e.g. where a callback can be registered) and how.
  - Related to the above, there should be as little juggling with e.g. 'this' arguments as possible.

How can I best achieve the above objectives?

**NOTE:** Since inheritance is a bit wonky for me in JavaScript I have not gone that path, I have also read that JS inheritance may decrease performance (though I suspect that at my required four levels of inheritance it would not be a problem).

**NOTE:** I am looking for a clean vanilla JS solution, I am not a big fan of all these frameworks that bloat the codebase needlessly.

Comment: JavaScript custom events should work [**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: `class SpecialRPG extends RPG { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @Nope: That sounds like an interesting appraoch - I am a bit concerned whether these events are lightweight enough? I will ready up on it though, thank you.

Comment: @cornergraf Usually you wouldn't need events or inheritance but have a main game loop that runs continuously checking the different states and respond to it as needed. The following link is a good starting read but I would probably look up standard game loops in JavaScript as well or with Canvas (if used/needed) etc..  - [**https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/how-should-i-write-a-main-game-loop**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/how-should-i-write-a-main-game-loop) Depending how much is going on and how accurate it needs to be, a basic while game-loop might suffice.

Comment: Actually calling empty functions isn't really inefficient compared to a check whether there is a callback.

Comment: @Nope: What I am implementing is not really a game loop - the character sheet is fairly static. The exception being that I am implementing a real-time optimization system that tries to optimize spending of XP and other resources on various stats - in that particular instance I have to calculate XP spending for many different combinations of stats, while simultaneously keeping track of rules that enforce minimum/maximum values for these stats, in some cases even interdependent). It is for these calculations I want the solution to be as lightweight as possible.

Comment: @cornergraf Ah, I see. The benefit of events then over function calls is the responsibility is in the right place IMHO :) - `CharacterSheet.prototype.handleSomeUserInteraction(){func1();func2();}` will have to be updated a lot as you add other things you want responding. Also, it means the character sheet is aware of how it is being used. While `CharacterSheet.prototype.handleSomeUserInteraction(){gameobject.dispatchEvent('CharacterXPDecreased')}` or similar, means the charactersheet is not responsible for updating the other systems but other system can respond if they like.

Comment: @Nope You are quite right I believe. Feel free to create an actual answer and I will at least upvote it. This discussion has already helped me understand the problem much better, though I have not entirely made up my mind about what to do yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have come up with so far - inspired by the event driven solution suggested by @Nope.

```
CharacterSheet.prototype.onUserInteraction = [];
CharacterSheet.prototype.handleSomeUserInteraction()  
{
    var _this = this;
    this.prototype.onUserInteraction.forEach(callback => {callback.call(_this);});
}

// Implementers then first create an implementation of the callback:
CharacterSheet.prototype.handleOnUserInteracation = function()
{
    // Do something here
}
// And then register the callback this way:
CharacterSheet.prototype.onUserInteraction.push(CharacterSheet.prototype.handleOnUserInteracation);
```

This is not as clean and intuitive as I would ideally like, but it ensures that the code written in the callback can be treated as if it was written directly for the CharacterSheet prototype, and I do not have to mess with true JS inheritance.

Feedback for this approach would be appreciated, and alternative solutions will be upvoted if you explain the advantages/disadvantages. If it's good enough I will gladly mark it as accepted also.

Please note that the above code was written from memory, so it might contain some minor mistakes.